# several table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, input

How does the code have to be edited if an external tex file is included (via \input)?
The external file should have its own independent table of contents.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    % renew \contentsline for toc to include hypertarget
    \let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
    \renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
    \hypertarget{toc#4}{}%
    \oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

    % renew \section to link to the toc
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\bf}
    {{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}
    {1pc}
    {}

    % renew \subsection to link to the toc
    \titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\bf}
    {{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsection.                    \thesubsection}{#1}}
    {1pc}{}

    % renew \subsubsection to link to the toc
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\normalfont\bf}
    {{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsubsection.        \thesubsubsection}{#1}}
    {1pc}{}

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents


    \section{abcd}


    \end{document}
```

Thanks for help!

---

@David Carliste
Here is the code:

```
%main.text
```

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[11.5pt]{scrartcl}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % sample text
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % to change headings
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,mwe}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, 
options= -s example_style.ist]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\newcommand{\wye}{\mathbin{\tikz[x=1ex,y=1ex]{\draw[line width=.1ex] (0,0)--(30:1)--++(-30:1) (30:1)--++(0,1);}}}

% renew \contentsline for toc to include hypertarget
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
    \hypertarget{toc#4}{}%
    \oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

% renew \section to link to the toc
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

% renew \subsection to link to the toc
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsection.\thesubsection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

% renew \subsubsection to link to the toc
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsubsection.\thesubsubsection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

\definecolor{MyCyan}{RGB}{0,255,255}
\definecolor{MyRed}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{MyGreen}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\definecolor{MyBlue}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{MyOrangeBrown}{RGB}{255,127,0}

\definecolor{LB}{RGB}{0,255,255}
\definecolor{BV}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{O}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{A}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{Z}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\definecolor{LK}{RGB}{255,87,255}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{
        left=0.2cm,
        right=0.2cm,
        top=0.2cm,
        bottom=0.2cm,
        bindingoffset=2mm
    }
    
    \newgeometry{
        left=1cm,
        right=1cm,
        top=1cm,
        bottom=1cm,
        bindingoffset=2mm
    }
    
    \UseRawInputEncoding
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \author{Marc} 
        \title{\"Ubersicht} 
        %\subtitle{eigene Pl\"ane}
        \date{} 
        \maketitle
    \end{titlepage}
    
    
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    
    \newpage

    \section{Geb\"aude}

    \subsection{Gesamt}
    \input{95283.tex}
    \subsection{Gesamt2}

    \section{Geb\"aude2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you probably need to clarify your question you only show one file so no one can use the code shown to see the issue or text answers.`\input` just acts as if the text were copied to that point it has no effect on grouping or the output, so may not be the right command to use, but without seeing what kind of files you need hard to say. you could for example include completed pdf files with their own toc with pdfpages package

Comment: This was still not clear. Is the first code as `\input` in your second code named `95283.tex`?

Comment: tocloft package's `\newlistof` might be what you want, depending on what you want.

Comment: Übersetzungstypen
Textübersetzung
Ausgangstext
​
309 / 5.000
Übersetzungsergebnisse
Übersetzung
There are two files (main.tex and 95283.tex).
The 95283.tex is integrated into the main.tex.
Both should have separate tables of contents.

The structure should look something like this:

main.tex:

Table of contents
1......A
1.1..abcd
1,2...efg


95283.tex:

Table of contents
1......B
1.1...hij
1.2...klm

Comment: note `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` is wrong (all files posted here are UTF-8) you should make your preamble more reasonable why specify tikz 4 times, why wpecify mwe and lipsum in a real document why hyperrref twice? why xcolor 3 times  plus color ? You still have provided no code that anyone can run:  you have just shown a document that `\input` some unshown file. You should remove all packages unrelated to the question and provide two small sample documents that you want to generate tables of contents for.